# c++ gcc string inlining

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, inline

I want to force strings to be allocated into local variables dynamically at run-time via assembly instructions ***without*** the string occupying memory in a data section (such as the read only data section).

The following seems to work perfectly:

```
char foo[] = "bar";
```

The assembly code becomes:

```
movl    $7496034, 40(%esp)
```

Thus, `foo` is initialized with `"bar"` via the `movl` instruction at run-time.

How can I force it to happen on all string operations?

For example, if I pass a string literal into a function:

```
testfunc("bar");
```

The string `"bar"` will be allocated in a section in this case.

Comment: `char foo[] = "bar"; testfunc( foo );` doesn't work?

Comment: I'm curious about the rationale for this.

Comment: @Andrew: this will force me to declare a variable everytime which is what im trying to avoid.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Believe me, you're not alone on that.

Comment: What real problem are you trying to solve? Your actual problem is not forcing the compiler to allocate strings on the stack. It's very likely that your real problem is something else, and it's just you think that allocating your strings on the stack is going to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes it indeed will. I need to not allocate the string in any sections. If you got a better solution than mine, please explain, keep in mind it must not be in any section.

Comment: What makes you believe that `"bar"` does not exist in a section for the `foo` initialization case?

Comment: @user3575889 You are not clear at all as to where your `char foo[] = "bar";` code is located. It does one thing in global scope and another inside of a function. Further, it's common in these cases to have the initial value stored in a section (e.g. `.rodata`) and later copied to a RAM-based `char[]`. And "dynamically built on runtime via asm instructions" can mean *either* 1) using an assembly loop to copy from ROM to RAM, (e.g. `for(...) *dest++ = *src++;`) or 2) using assembly instructions to store immediate-mode values into RAM (e.g. `dest[0] = 'T'; dest[1] = 'e'; dest[2] = 's'; ` etc.).

Comment: It seems to me that gcc does this only if foo is char[], but not for const char[]. I don't know why.

Comment: "bar" is still in your code's text section.

Answer (score 5):

The technique you show only works for your special case. In general, the compiler is free to place the contents of strings into the section. For example, with this small tweak:

```
char foo[] = "bar\0";
```

The string will now appear in the read only data section.

Knowing that the technique is not guaranteed to always work, you can use a macro to automate the technique so that you can pass strings to functions without using pointers to the read only section.

```
#define string_invoke(Func, Str)        \
        []() -> decltype(Func(NULL)) {  \
            char foo[] = Str;           \
            return Func(foo);           \
        }()
```

Comment: What kind of "section" do you think the op is talking about?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: Likely the `rodata` section, if ELF. The compiler has an optimization to turn strings into numeric literals and initialize accordingly. I was illustrating the optimization doesn't always happen, and the initialization is a `memcpy` from the `rodata`.

Answer (score 3):

You have a four-character string you want to initialize with four characters ("bar" plus the null-terminator.) The compiler recognizes an opportunity for an awesome micro-optimization and saves a four-byte integer into the string which has the same bit pattern as "bar". On 64-bit machines, the compiler might also use this technique for 8-character strings. Wonderful! But don't expect this optimization to be applicable wherever you use C strings.

When a function takes a C string as a parameter, for instance, it's expecting a pointer to an array, not an integer.

Contorting you code to force specific compiler optimizations is a great way to write unmaintainable, brittle code. You're better off writing clear code using efficient algorithms and enjoying whatever awesome optimizations the compiler can apply.

Comment: Nice explanation why such useless programmer side optimization should be avoided.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not an authoritative answer. You say "might" and cite no source. What we are looking for is the explanation of that GCC behaviour, what triggers it.

Comment: I'm not trying to be authoritative. I said GCC "might" use the same optimization because it's theoretically possible, but I didn't check nor do I care. I explained the GCC behavior and then said don't force your coding style to try to invoke this optimization.